# SonarQube qulity gate color on dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a strange bug/issue in Sonar Qube. There is a project X that has a Quality Gate with condition: Coverage on new code < 80 (error). In this project the value for this is ~50, so SQ should mark this as error with red color. On Project X details site it's ok:

[image]

But on dashboard (it's SonarQube 5.6.6 LTS) the value is not colored:

[image]

How to set change this behavior, so that SQ will color also the value in dashboard? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values that cause projects to fail the quality gate are no longer highlighted in red on the project homepage, and this is not configurable.

Comment: Hello G. Ann - This also reflects to dashboard? The non-highlighted value is on dashboard where we have a few of project summaries.